# Entity object to connect to 2 databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible for an entity object to connect to 2 databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the model is based on a single database.  If you need data from another database (assuming SQL Server), create a view against the other database and import the view into your model.